# How to align equations to the left?

Tags: equations, align, flalign

I have this equation on Overleaf that aligns to the right instead of the left. I have followed instructions on other questions found here but it doesn't work.

```
{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\begin{flalign}
     -\frac{\tau}{2} \sum (x_n - \mu)^2 -b_0\tau -\frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2} (\mu - \mu_0)^2 \\
     = -\frac{\tau}{2}\sum(x_n^2 + \mu^2 - 2x_n\mu) - b_0\tau - \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0)\\
     = -\frac{\tau}{2}(\sum x_n^2 + N\mu^2 - 2\mu\sum x_n) - b_0\tau - \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0)
\end{flalign}%
}%
```

[image]

How can I align to the left?

Comment: Please make your given code snippet compilable ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i guess that you are looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \MoveEqLeft
-\frac{\tau}{2}\sum (x_n-\mu)^2-b_0\tau
    -\frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)^2 \\
    & = - \frac{\tau}{2}\sum(x_n^2 + \mu^2 - 2x_n\mu) - b_0\tau -
            \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0)\\
    & = -\frac{\tau}{2}\Bigl(\sum x_n^2 + N\mu^2 - 2\mu\sum x_n\Bigr) - b_0\tau -
            \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0))
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much. i consider your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for not being sufficiently clear earlier about where the large parentheses should go. I've taken the liberty of providing an update.

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much. i should see, which parenthesis are in pair.

Comment: If there are more equalities in the same line and you'd like to them to break, to the next line, when there's no more space, how can you do that?

Comment: @Verónica, on the same way as are break other lines now. if this make you some problem, please ask new question where provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
 -& \frac{\tau}{2}\sum (x_n-\mu)^2-b_0\tau -\frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)^2 \notag \\
  &= -\frac{\tau}{2}\sum(x_n^2 + \mu^2 - 2x_n\mu) - b_0\tau -
      \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0)                                   \\
  &= -\frac{\tau}{2}\Bigl(\sum x_n^2 + N\mu^2 - 2\mu\sum x_n\Bigr) - b_0\tau - 
      \frac{\lambda_0\tau}{2}(\mu^2 + \mu_0^2 - 2\mu\mu_0)) \notag
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

> [image]