# How to align many equalities on a line to the left? (there is another line below that, when I move it to the left, the line above moves to the right)

Tags: equations, formatting, align, amsmath, flalign

How to align this expressions to the left? and the letter `y` too?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
   & = 
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot \dfrac{\partial n_i^m}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}\label{partialF/w}
  &  =
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}
   & =
    \left(\dfrac{\partial n_i^{m+1} }{\partial n_{i}^m}\right)^T\dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}& =
  %  \letf(
    w_{i,j}^{m+1}\dfrac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\\
     \implies
     \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}=\dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}=  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\dfrac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1} \label{F/w simp}
    \\
    y \nonumber
 \end{flalign}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, that for some reason, in the image above (which corresponds to the code above) the `\implies` is on the left (as expected) and in the image below is centered, I don't know why. The original document that I have is the image below.

[image]

I've checked this other post [How to align equations to the left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467113/how-to-align-equations-to-the-left) and I followed the suggestions of this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467116/, but as you can see, it didn't work in my case.

Could someone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: this can't possib;ly all fit on one line,  have you omitted some `\\ ` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, this is can't fit in one line, I did add \\   before   \implies.

Comment: it can't fit on two lines, I just added `&` before all the = and `\\ ` at the end of each previous row.

Comment: What's with the `y` term on a line all by itself?

Comment: @Mico It's supposed to link the rest of equations I have in the doc. `y` stands for an "and" in english.

Comment: In that case, you should render `y` in text mode, *outside* the displayed equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you gain in clarity by forcing alignments. And, since the “implies” symbol can be replaced by words, it should.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
%\label{partialF/w}
\pder{\hat{F}}{w_{i,j}^m}
& = \pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^m}\cdot \pder{n_i^m}{w_{i,j}^m}
\\
& = \pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
\\
& = \left(\pder{n_i^{m+1}}{n_{i}^m}\right)^{\!T}\pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
\\
& = w_{i,j}^{m+1}\pder{f^m(n_j^m)}{n_j^m}\pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
\end{align*}
or, in summary,
\begin{equation}\label{F/w simp}
\pder{\hat{F}}{w_{i,j}^m}
= \pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
= w_{i,j}^{m+1}\pder{f^m(n_j^m)}{n_j^m} \pder{\hat{F}}{n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I defined a shorthand for partial derivatives that makes input less painful.

The equation numbers in the derivation have been removed as it's just a technical argument and the last equation includes the same information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. Also thanks for the shorthand `\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}` I didn't know it existed.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:**
Corrected are MWE -- added missed code lines and considere changes which OP gives in comment below:.

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
  & = \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot \frac{\partial n_i^m}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}  \label{partialF/w}      \\
  &  =
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot
    a_j^{m-1}               \\
  & =
    \left(\frac{\partial n_i^{m+1} }{\partial n_{i}^m}\right)^T\frac{\partial\hat{ F}}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot
    a_j^{m-1}               \\
  & = w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot
    a_j^{m-1}               \\
\implies  \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}    
    & = \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
      =  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m} 
                      \frac{\partial\hat{F}}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}           
        \label{partialF/w simp}
\end{align}
y
\end{document}
```

or this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
  & = \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot \frac{\partial n_i^m}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
        \label{partialF/w}      \\
  &  = \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1} 
     = \left(\frac{\partial n_i^{m+1} }{\partial n_{i}^m}\right)^T
             \frac{\partial\hat{ F}}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}               
                        \notag  \\
  & = w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot
    a_j^{m-1}   
                                \\
\implies \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
  & = \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
    =  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
        \label{F/w simp}
\shortintertext{y}
\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
  & = \text{continuation of derivation}
        \label{partialF/extra}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Verónica, ca me explain of meaning of `y` (and, as you say) on the end of equation. Is it part of text which follows equation or a text between to equations? So far, it seems that I wrongly include it in equation (as variable). In latter case it can be inserted between equations as `\shortintertext{y}`.

Comment: @Verónica, see edited answer.

Comment: The `y` was meant as a text, yes. I think it's the former code. You forgot the `\end{align} \end{document}` btw. I've modified the code that comes after \implies to: `\implies               
\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
   =\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot a_j^{m-1}
                               =  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1}  
        \label{partialF/w simp}`. When I do this, all the code above \implies, turns to the right.

Comment: Why is that? and how to move it to the left?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably similar to Zarko's, it fits on the page but I couldn't guess what you wanted to do with the floating y at the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
   & = 
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot \dfrac{\partial n_i^m}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}\label{partialF/w}\\
  &  =
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\\
   & =
    \left(\dfrac{\partial n_i^{m+1} }{\partial n_{i}^m}\right)^T\dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\\
  & =
  %  \letf(
    w_{i,j}^{m+1}\dfrac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\\
     &\implies\\
     \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
     &=\dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\\
    &=  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\dfrac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1} \label{F/w simp}
    \\
    y \nonumber
 \end{flalign}
 \end{document}
```

Or perhaps as two alignments

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
   & = 
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot \frac{\partial n_i^m}{\partial w_{i,j}^m} \label{partialF/w} \\
  &  =
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}  \nonumber\\
   & =
    \left(\frac{\partial n_i^{m+1} }{\partial n_{i}^m}\right)^T\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}  \nonumber\\
  & =
     w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot a_j^{m-1} \nonumber
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
     \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
     &=\frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}\label{F/w simp} \\
    &=  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\frac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \frac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1} \nonumber
 \end{align}
something about $y$
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm with you, except for the need to assign the row with `\implies` an equation number of its own...

Comment: @Mico er well yes there needs to be some  `\nonumber`  I put the implication on its own as I couldn't see where to put it. I think I would write this as two separate alignments with "this implies" written in words between the two parts. There doesn't seem to be any semantoc meaning between the = in the first chain and the second

Comment: @Mico better?...

Comment: Thank sir for your help. `y` is meant to be as a connector for the rest of the stuff that I have in the doc. I thought it was a good idea :)

Comment: In your first code, I edited it to `\implies
     \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial w_{i,j}^m}
     =\dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^m}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1}
    =  w_{i,j}^{m+1}\dfrac{\partial f^m(n_j^m)}{\partial n_j^m}%\right)
    \dfrac{\partial\hat F}{\partial n_{i}^{m+1}}\cdot 
    a_j^{m-1} \label{F/w simp}` and displayed it all in one line, and to the left. As I wanted. However the rest of the code above it, moved to the right, why? How can be stacked on the left?

Comment: @Verónica you removed the `&` alignment point  all of your first line is the left side of the equation so everything after a & will be to the right of that. you can put two = on a lne (but it makes it harder to read) but then you want no alignment at all (and use gather not align) or use a & just before teh first & on each line